# how to display multiple select list after node submit

Tags: drupal, form-api

I have been reading around and just havent found any type of answer.

I have a multiple select list and need to take the the values of the multiple select and pass them to an API call.
But I dont understand how drupal renders the multiple select list and how to habdle this.

Can someone please explain this to me or if you have come across any docs that explain this, please point me in the right direction.

Also, when I try to write the select to the db, I always get a the value 1... never changes...

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Solved:
The Multiple select is stored in an associative array where the key value pair are taken from the key value of the list, this means that both the key and value get the same value.

I did this by using devels dvm(); function which displays the array in the message area after the node was saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
The Multiple select is stored in an associative array where the key value pair are taken from the key value of the list, this means that both the key and value get the same value.

I did this by using devels dvm(); function which displays the array in the message area after the node was saved.